# How to implement Android-ViewpagerIndicator correctly in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using ViewPagerIndicator library in my android app. I am getting an error saying,

01-14 17:54:38.195: E/AndroidRuntime(12200): Caused by: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating 
class com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator

My XML code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
    android:padding="10dip"
    app:fillColor="#FF888888"
    app:pageColor="#88FF0000"
    app:radius="10dp"
    app:strokeColor="#FF000000"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my activity code is,

```
public class ProfileActivity extends FragmentActivity {


ViewPager pager;
CirclePageIndicator indicator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_step1);
    pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    ArrayList<fragmentViewPager> frags = new ArrayList<fragmentViewPager>();

    fragmentViewPager f1 = new fragmentViewPager(1);
    fragmentViewPager f2 = new fragmentViewPager(2);
    fragmentViewPager f3 = new fragmentViewPager(3);

    frags.add(f1);
    frags.add(f2);
    frags.add(f3);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), frags);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    indicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);
  }
}
```

I have added the library correctly. What is the wrong with this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some error in your XML some were try this code

```
    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FBFBFB"
    android:padding="15dip"
    android:textColor="#2FB3E3"
    app:footerColor="#2FB3E3"
    app:footerIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:footerIndicatorStyle="underline"
    app:footerLineHeight="1dp"
    app:selectedBold="true"
    app:selectedColor="#0393D9" 
    app1:strokeColor="#BCA99F"

    />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an error with your XML code 
the color is wrote with 6 digits not 8 digits . (red green blue )two for each color 
so you can't write 
`android:background="#FFCCCCCC"` 
 the correct is `android:background="#FFCCCC"`
do this for all your colors
like that

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
android:id="@+id/indicator"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFCCCC"
android:padding="10dip"
app:fillColor="#FF8888"
app:pageColor="#88FF00"
app:radius="10dp"
app:strokeColor="#FF0000"
app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

Comment: I corrected those mistakes. But still I'm getting that error

Comment: you have some error in your XML some were i will write another answer with the `CirclePageIndicator` xml tag thats works with me